# Why does converting a blob to a data URI result in a different URI than the direct data URI method?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm doing an experiment and I discovered converting a Canvas to a blob then to a data URI results in a different URI than getting the data URI direct from the canvas. The contents when opened are pretty much the same on both URIs.

How can I get the same URI result as the direct data URI method when using the blob method?

```js
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let text = "Bufferoverrun";

ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.font = "16px 'Arial'";
ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
ctx.rotate(.05);
ctx.fillStyle = "#f60";
ctx.fillRect(125, 1, 62, 20);
ctx.fillStyle = "#069";
ctx.fillText(text, 2, 15);
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(102, 200, 0, 0.7)";
ctx.fillText(text, 4, 17);
ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
ctx.shadowColor = "blue";
ctx.fillRect(-20, 10, 234, 5);

const blobToBase64 = blob => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
        };
    });
};

canvas.toBlob(async function (result) {
    let blobToURL = await blobToBase64(result)
    if (blobToURL != canvas.toDataURL()) {
        console.log("Data mismatch");
    } else {
        console.log("Match")
    }
})
```

I've looked at Chrome's Blink internals and cannot find anything that explains the change.

[Canvas Element Source Code - Blink](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/canvas/html_canvas_element.cc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current difference lies in how `toBlob` and `toDataURL` handle differently the color-space conversion.

`toBlob` may in some case retain the current color-space and include it in the produced Blob, `toDataURL` won't ever, and when `toBlob` does, it uses an other path to do that conversion.

Here is where they do the conversion for [toDataURL](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/platform/graphics/image_data_buffer.cc;drc=2ac64302ae161cd6b5e4b1254497bdf5fd6d3415;l=179)  and here is for [toBlob](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/core/html/canvas/canvas_async_blob_creator.cc;drc=2ac64302ae161cd6b5e4b1254497bdf5fd6d3415;l=215).

---

Funnily enough, Chrome will generate the same bitmaps from both files when painting them back on a canvas again, but if you save both results to disk and draw them in a browser that does check at the source color-space like Firefox, you'll see they actually are different.

---

Note that it may not be the only place where you will find difference between both methods.

For instance, I also noticed that `toBlob` will get influenced by the fact the canvas is accelerated or not (below demo requires `chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`):

```js
const test = (accelerated) => {
  const HW = accelerated ? "accelerated" : "not-accelerated"
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d', {
    willReadFrequently: !accelerated
  });
  let text = "Bufferoverrun";

  ctx.fillStyle = "#f60";
  ctx.fillRect(125, 1, 62, 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#069";
  ctx.fillText(text, 2, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(102, 200, 0, 0.7)";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
  ctx.shadowColor = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(-20, 10, 234, 5);

  canvas.toBlob(async function(result) {
    let blobToURL = await blobToBase64(result)
    const data = canvas.toDataURL();
    if (blobToURL != data) {
      console.log(HW, "Data mismatch");
    } else {
      console.log(HW, "Match")
    }
  });

  function blobToBase64(blob) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        resolve(reader.result);
      };
    });
  }
};
test(true);
test(false);
```

---

And I should note that **you should not expect these methods to return the same values** anyway. Nothing in the specs requires that and quite on the contrary one could expect that since `toBlob` is asynchronous and performs its encoding *in parallel*, it would use slower but better quality options for its encoder than the synchronous `toDataURL`.

But if for your own case you want to have the same results through both methods, you can force software rendering by disabling Hardware Acceleration (`chrome://settings/?search=hardware acceleration`), and they will produce the same result.

---

From the comments OP explained that they actually are in a web extension, and area actually dealing with an OffscreenCanvas, which doesn't have a `toDataURL` method.

So first, **in Firefox** there is a [`demote` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Internal_APIs_chrome-context_only) on the 2D context available to ChromeContexts (web extensions), which should allow to force using the software-renderer, **but Chrome didn't implement this feature**.

Now regarding the OffscreenCanvas in a worker case, one way around is to call `toDataURL()` from the main thread on an HTMLCanvasElement from which we grabbed our OffscreenCanvas:

```js
const worker = new Worker( worker_url );
const workercanvas = document.createElement( "canvas" );
const offscreen = workercanvas.transferControlToOffscreen();
worker.postMessage(offscreen, [offscreen]);
worker.onmessage = (evt) => {
  const fromworker = workercanvas.toDataURL();
  const frommain = getDataURLFromMain();
  console.log( fromworker === frommain ? "Match" : "Data mismatch" );
};
```

```html
<script>
// boiler plate prepare scripts content for SO's StackSnippet
const drawing_ops = `
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const text = "Bufferoverrun";

  ctx.textBaseline = "top";
  ctx.font = "16px 'Arial'";
  ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
  ctx.rotate(.05);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#f60";
  ctx.fillRect(125, 1, 62, 20);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#069";
  ctx.fillText(text, 2, 15);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(102, 200, 0, 0.7)";
  ctx.fillText(text, 4, 17);
  ctx.shadowBlur = 10;
  ctx.shadowColor = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(-20, 10, 234, 5);
`;
const getDataURLFromMain = new Function(`
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
${ drawing_ops }
  return canvas.toDataURL();
`);
const worker_script = new Blob( [ `
onmessage = (evt) => {
  const canvas = evt.data;
${ drawing_ops }
  if( ctx.commit ) { // might require WebPlatformFeatures flags
    ctx.commit();
    postMessage("");
  }
  else {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => postMessage(""));  
  }
};` ] );
const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL( worker_script );
</script>
```

[Also available as a glitch](https://curvy-goldenrod-asiago.glitch.me/) since it might be clearer.

Comment: is there any way to do this directly on Javascript without flags? There happen to be a method called demote on Chrome CanvasContext but I can't find it on prototype yet. Is it got replaced with something else?

Comment: I know one way but it's a nuclear option. I wouldn't consider it as viable solution.

Comment: I don't think there is any no, willWriteFrequently which I use in my demo is the closest but isn't enough here, and demote is only accessible on `://chrome` context (i.e from a browser extension). Well one obvious way is to overwrite toBlob so it uses toDataURL. But why do you need both methods to return the same? You won't have the same results on 2 different machines anyway. Ps curious about your "nuclear option" too.

Comment: I am actually using this inside a Chrome Extension and I don't see demote there either. 

To be specific, I'm not really asking toBlob to produce same as DataURI and in favor any other methods that produce same result as DataURI. 

I use this inside a worker with OffScreenCanvas and there is no DataURI. For the question, I would say I generalized the problem because the problem reproducible with main thread too.

Comment: I missed your demo. It seems it produce same result on both methods. By the way, Do I have to define "demote" property inside contextAttributes?

Comment: Actually, your demo breaks if one compare a DataURI created without willWriteFrequently property. It seems true and false on that property doesn't matter, it produce same results but without that property, different results.

Comment: Ah my bad, I had the *Experimental Web Platforms* flags set, I thought the `willReadFrequently` option already made it unflagged, but apparently not. Regarding demote I did a bit of research and could only find it in [FF's source](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/webidl/CanvasRenderingContext2D.webidl#120), maybe the MDN's article should get updated. And regarding your case, I did edit my answer with an other solution which may be ok with you.

Comment: your new solution works for MV2 and MV3 doesn't have a DOM

Comment: What are "MV2" and "MV3"? If your environment doesn't have a DOM, how does it matter it doesn't return the same result as toDataURL? toDataURL must not exist anyway. Once again, two different machines will produce different outputs.

Comment: MV2, MV3 are extension standards. The former life time will end soon while the latter continue for 5-6 years from now. 

I could compare the URI from my website and extension 

I guess only nuclear option is left, skia ... .

Comment: If you only need it to compare the results against your own website, why don't you only use toBlob there? toDataURL should be avoided as much as possible anyway.

Comment: Ps: I'm really not into extensions but I don't see from https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-overview/ where it's been said they'll remove content-scripts, quite on contrary it says they will introduce *Dynamic content scripts*.

Comment: They are moving from background_html to service_workers